# Test Class is passing but however the code coverage is 0% while deploying

Tags: apex

I have an apex trigger on contact which will trigger an email when an email field has been changed and picklist values is either No or Null

The following is the Apex trigger code

Trigger:

```
trigger Contact_OnBusinessEmailChange_Trigger on Contact (after update) {

        List<String> mailList = new List<String>();
  List<String> mailAddresses = new List<String>(); 
  Group g = [SELECT (select userOrGroupId from groupMembers) FROM group WHERE name = 'TCSTestGroup'];
  for (GroupMember gm : g.groupMembers) 
  {
   mailList.add(gm.userOrGroupId);
  }
  User[] usr = [SELECT email FROM user WHERE id IN :mailList];
  for(User u : usr) 
  {
  mailAddresses.add(u.email);
  } 
        string messagebody;
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Contact c : trigger.new) { 
            Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id); 
            if ((old.Email != c.Email) && ((c.Opt_in_to_Tracking__c== 'No') ||(c.Opt_in_to_Tracking__c== null))) {  
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setToAddresses(mailAddresses);
                email.setReplyTo('noreply@salesforce.com');
                email.setSenderDisplayName('IT Salesforce Support');
                email.setSubject('Notification: Email Address Change');
                messagebody='<html><body>The Business Email for the contact "' +c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName + '" has been updated from ' + old.Email + ' to ' + c.Email +' by '+c.Updated_By__c + '.<br/><br/>The Contact\'s further details below:<br/><br/>Contact\'s First Name:'+c.FirstName+'<br/>Contact\'s Last Name:'+c.LastName+'<br/>Contact\'s ID:'+c.Id+'';
                email.setHtmlBody(messagebody);
                emails.add(email);
            }
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
```

And the below is the Apex Test Class

```
@isTest
private class ContactOnBusinessEmailChangeTestClass{
private static testMethod void mailchangecheckvalid(){
//for new contact valid test
   Account grpAccnt = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_grp1_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Group',Source_System_ID__c='test5923');
        insert grpAccnt;

        Account accnt1 = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_accnt1_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Account',Source_System_ID__c='test594',
                parentId=grpAccnt.Id);
        insert accnt1;
        Account acc1 = new Account(Name='UpdateAccSSTest_accLoc1_11Dec_2015',Account_Type__c ='Account Location',
                Active__c = true,Source_System_ID__c='test',parentId=accnt1.Id);
        insert acc1;
        Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName='UpdateAccSSTest_con1_11Dec_2015',LastName='Test contact1',accountid=acc1.id,
                Business_Unit__c='GCF',Email='mytestmail@genre.com');
        insert con1;

con1.Email='mytestmail2@genre.com';
try{update con1; }catch(DmlException e){System.Debug('Failure happened');}


System.assertEquals('mytestmail2@genre.com',con1.Email);
}

private static testMethod void mailchangecheckinvalid(){
//for new contact invalid test
   Account grpAccnt = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_grp2_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Group',Source_System_ID__c='test5927');
        insert grpAccnt;

        Account accnt1 = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_accnt2_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Account',Source_System_ID__c='test5947',
                parentId=grpAccnt.Id);
        insert accnt1;
        Account acc1 = new Account(Name='UpdateAccSSTest_accLoc2_11Dec_2015',Account_Type__c ='Account Location',
                Active__c = true,Source_System_ID__c='test',parentId=accnt1.Id);
        insert acc1;
        Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName='UpdateAccSSTest_con1_17Mar_2011',LastName='Test contact2',accountid=acc1.id,
                Business_Unit__c='GCF',Email='mytestmail3@genre.com');
        insert con1;


con1.Email='mytestmail4@genre.com';

try{update con1; }catch(DmlException e){System.Debug('Failure happened');}

System.assertnotEquals('mytestmail3@genre.com',con1.Email);
}

}
```

Could you please tell me how to increase the code coverage to deploy this trigger

Comment: You should never use a `try`/`catch` and then just `debug`. You are going to "pass" tests that should really fail, and you should always take a specific action in your `catch` block, unless you have a very good reason not to. If you let your `DmlException` fail your test will be ***far more meaningful***.

Comment: Did my answer below help? Are you still stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes that should hopefully help out. First, in your trigger, I have moved where you do your new contact checking. By checking the criteria first and building the emails, we can reduce the number of SOQL statements that are fired when they are not needed (every time a contact is updated and does not meet your criteria):

---

```
trigger Contact_OnBusinessEmailChange_Trigger on Contact (after update) 
{
  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

  for (Contact c : trigger.new)
  { 
    Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id); 
    if ((old.Email != c.Email) && ((c.Opt_in_to_Tracking__c == 'No') || (c.Opt_in_to_Tracking__c == null)))
    {  
      Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
      email.setToAddresses(mailAddresses);
      email.setReplyTo('noreply@salesforce.com');
      email.setSenderDisplayName('IT Salesforce Support');
      email.setSubject('Notification: Email Address Change');
      messagebody='<html><body>The Business Email for the contact "' + c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName + '" has been updated from ' + old.Email + ' to ' + c.Email +' by ' + c.Updated_By__c + '.<br/><br/>The Contact\'s further details below:<br/><br/>Contact\'s First Name:'+c.FirstName+'<br/>Contact\'s Last Name:'+c.LastName+'<br/>Contact\'s ID:'+c.Id+'';
      email.setHtmlBody(messagebody);
      emails.add(email);
    }
  }

  if(emails.size() > 0)
  {
    List<String> mailList = new List<String>();
    List<String> mailAddresses = new List<String>(); 
    Group g = [SELECT (SELECT userOrGroupId FROM GroupMembers) FROM Group WHERE name = 'TCSTestGroup' LIMIT 1];

    for (GroupMember gm : g.GroupMembers) 
    {
      mailList.add(gm.userOrGroupId);
    }

    List<User> users = [SELECT email FROM user WHERE id IN :mailList];
    for(User u : users) 
    {
      mailAddresses.add(u.email);
    }

    for(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email : emails)
    {
      email.setToAddresses(mailAddresses);
    }
  }
  Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

---

Next I've updated your test classes. It looks like you don't create your group and group members. You also want to check your assertions for ensuring that the email was sent:

```
@isTest
private class ContactOnBusinessEmailChangeTestClass
{
private static testMethod void mailchangecheckvalid()
{
    // Create our public group that we are sending our email to
    Group testGroup = new Group(Name='TCSTestGroup', DeveloperName='TCSTestGroup_Test');
    insert testGroup;

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isActive = TRUE AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];

    List<GroupMember> listGroupMember = new List<GroupMember>();  
    // loop the users that have been created
    for (User user : users)
    {
        GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(); 
        gm.GroupId = testGroup.id;
        gm.UserOrGroupId = user.id;
        listGroupMember.add(gm);   
    } 
    insert listGroupMember;

    //for new contact valid test
    Account grpAccnt = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_grp1_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Group',Source_System_ID__c='test5923');
    insert grpAccnt;

    Account accnt1 = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_accnt1_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Account',Source_System_ID__c='test594',
            parentId=grpAccnt.Id);
    insert accnt1;
    Account acc1 = new Account(Name='UpdateAccSSTest_accLoc1_11Dec_2015',Account_Type__c ='Account Location',
            Active__c = true,Source_System_ID__c='test',parentId=accnt1.Id);
    insert acc1;
    Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName='UpdateAccSSTest_con1_11Dec_2015',LastName='Test contact1',accountid=acc1.id,
            Business_Unit__c='GCF',Email='mytestmail@genre.com');
    insert con1;

    con1.Email='mytestmail2@genre.com';
    try
    {
        test.startTest();
        update con1; 
        test.topTest();
    }
    catch(DmlException e)
    {
        system.assert(FALSE, 'DML Exception Occured');
    }
    // Check that email was sent because our Opt_in_to_Tracking__c is set to NULL
    System.assert(Limits.getEmailInvocations()==1);
}

private static testMethod void mailchangecheckinvalid()
{
    // Create our public group that we are sending our email to
    Group testGroup = new Group(Name='TCSTestGroup', DeveloperName='TCSTestGroup_Test');
    insert testGroup;

    List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE isActive = TRUE AND Profile.Name = 'System Administrator' LIMIT 1];

    List<GroupMember> listGroupMember = new List<GroupMember>();  
    // loop the users that have been created
    for (User user : users)
    {
        GroupMember gm = new GroupMember(); 
        gm.GroupId = testGroup.id;
        gm.UserOrGroupId = user.id;
        listGroupMember.add(gm);   
    } 
    insert listGroupMember;

    //for new contact invalid test
    Account grpAccnt = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_grp2_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Group',Source_System_ID__c='test5927');
    insert grpAccnt;

    Account accnt1 = new Account(name='UpdateAccSSTest_accnt2_11Dec_2015',account_type__c='Account',Source_System_ID__c='test5947',
            parentId=grpAccnt.Id);
    insert accnt1;
    Account acc1 = new Account(Name='UpdateAccSSTest_accLoc2_11Dec_2015',Account_Type__c ='Account Location',
            Active__c = true,Source_System_ID__c='test',parentId=accnt1.Id);
    insert acc1;
    Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName='UpdateAccSSTest_con1_17Mar_2011',LastName='Test contact2',accountid=acc1.id,
            Business_Unit__c='GCF',Email='mytestmail3@genre.com');
    insert con1;

    con1.Email='mytestmail4@genre.com';
    con1.Opt_in_to_Tracking__c = 'Yes';

    try
    {
        test.startTest();
        update con1; 
        test.topTest();
    }
    catch(DmlException e)
    {
        system.assert(FALSE, 'DML Exception Occured');
    }
    // Check that no email was sent because our Opt_in_to_Tracking__c is set to Yes
    System.assert(Limits.getEmailInvocations()==0);
}
}
```

---

Comment: you forgot to actually send the email (easy to do when rewriting an OP's code); testing emailInvocations limit can be fragile if other code is added later over time to triggers / handler classes that also send email.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated the answer with the send email portion.

Comment: With the trigger as it is implemented, is there a less fragile way to test? I'm always looking for ways to improve :)

Comment: I do it indirectly by always saving a Task when I send an email.  The I check to see the Task is inserted.  Provides a nice audit trail. However, this assumes code is written to tightly couple task + email. Others might have a better idea